# Searching entry of xml with BeautifulSoup

Tags: beautifulsoup

I know that there are many questions to this topic.. But I can't answer my question with that..

Can someone help me how to do that?

My xml file looks like that:

```
...
<object>
<acronym>Mmachc</acronym>
<alias-tags>1810037K07Rik RP23-177C18.3</alias-tags>
<chromosome-id>49</chromosome-id>
<ensembl-id nil="true"/>
<entrez-id>67096</entrez-id>
<genomic-reference-update-id>491928275</genomic-reference-update-id>
<homologene-id>12082</homologene-id>
<id>42939</id>
<legacy-ensembl-gene-id nil="true"/>
<name>
methylmalonic aciduria cblC type, with homocystinuria
</name>
<organism-id>2</organism-id>
<original-name>
</original-name>
<original-symbol>Mmachc</original-symbol>
<reference-genome-id nil="true"/>
<sphinx-id>95240</sphinx-id>
<version-status>no change</version-status>
</object>
<object>
...
```

So if I now want to search the object that contains e.g. the entrez-id 67096 to see which acronym it has.. I tried first:

```
url = "http://api.brain-map.org/api/v2/data/query.xml?num_rows=10000&start_row=10001&&criteria=model::Gene,rma::criteria,products[abbreviation$eq%27Mouse%27]"
req = requests.get(url)
doc = req.text
root = etree.XML(doc)
soup = BeautifulSoup(doc)

dict1 = {}

for object in soup.find_all('object'):
    dict1[object.find('entrez-id') == 67096]
```

The output for that is KeyError: False..

Can someone help me with that?
Also if I try to find it as string '67096' I got key error false..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need beautifulsoup here; just try something like:

```
target = root.xpath('//entrez-id[.="67096"]/preceding-sibling::acronym/text()')
target[0]
```

Output:

```
'Mmachc'
```